# Regular expression in Python for detecting numbers that are integers, floats or in the scientific notation

Tags: python, regex

How can I create a regular expression for accepting numbers in Python? The numbers can be either integers, floats or of the format 3e+3 or 3e-3.

I want to match only the beginning of the string, and if a number in any of the above mentioned formats is present, return that number and the rest of the string.

**Edit**:

For example,

**Input>>** 290.07abcd
**Output>>** [290.07, abcd]

**Input>>** abc123
**Output>>** None

Also, only the first occurrence is to be checked for.

For example,

**Input>>** -390-400abc

**Output>>**[-390, -400abc]

How can I do this using Python? I have tried the following, but it is not giving me the expected output:

```
import re
r = input()
x = re.search('^[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?([+-][eE]\d+)?', r)
if x:
    print("x present: ", x.group())
else:
    print(None)
```

For example,

**Input>>** 100abc

**Output>>** x present:  100

---

**Input>>** abc100

**Output>>** x present:

**Expected Output>>** None

Comment: Try something and show what you tried, the result, and what input.output shows your attempt isn't right.

Comment: You show a few specific examples, but are you interested in matching anything that would be accepted by the Python interpreter as a floating point value?  For example, `.123e2` is a valid floating point expression (no leading 0 before the decimal point, and no explicit sign in the exponent).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, I would like to accept anything that is a valid floating point number

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142309/python-regex-to-get-float-number-from-string.  The linked question is about a much more restricted set of inputs.  Note that there is no mention of scientific notation in the question or in the answer of the so-called duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility.  The pattern for a number is

```
number_pattern = "[+-]?((\d+\.\d*)|(\.\d+)|(\d+))([eE][+-]?\d+)?"
```

The pattern consists of:

- optional sign;
- three alternatives for the main part of the number:

  - one or more digits, followed by a decimal point, followed by zero or more digits;
  - a decimal point, followed by one or more digits;
  - one or more digits (no decimal point);
- optional exponential part, consisting of:

  - `e` or `E`;
  - optional sign;
  - one or more digits.

The first and third alternatives for the main part of the number can be combined to consist of one or more digits, optionally followed by a decimal point followed by zero or more digits.  The number pattern is then

```
number_pattern = "[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+))([eE][+-]?\d+)?"
```

You can use this to create a function that does what you asked:

```
pattern = "(" + number_pattern + ")(.*)"
compiled = re.compile(pattern)

def number_split(s):
    match = compiled.match(s)
    if match is None:
        return None
    groups = match.groups()
    return groups[0], groups[-1]
```

Some examples:

```
In [4]: print(number_split("290.07abcd"))
('290.07', 'abcd')

In [5]: print(number_split("abc123"))
None

In [6]: print(number_split("-390-400abc"))
('-390', '-400abc')

In [7]: print(number_split("0.e-3"))
('0.e-3', '')

In [8]: print(number_split("0x"))
('0', 'x')

In [9]: print(number_split(".123e2"))
('.123e2', '')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I just wanted to confirm if the following is acceptable as well:

`def number_split(s):

    x = re.search(number_pattern, s)
    if x:
        return x.group(), s[x.end():]
    else:
        return None


s = input()
x = number_split(s)
print(x)`

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this**

```
^[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?([+-][eE]\d+)?$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `[+-]`- Matches `+` or `-`.
- `\d*` - Matches zero or more digits.
- `(\.\d+)?` - Matches `.` followed by one or more digit.
- `([+-][eE]\d+)?` - Matches `+` or `-` followed by e or E followed by digits.
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYpsfh/6/)

Comment: I would also allow +/- at the start of the string and e/E as exponent then you need 1 or more digits after the e/E

Comment: @SteveBarnes added `+` or `-` at the start and at least one digit after e/E

Comment: Have you tested this with `.123`?

Comment: You fixed the bulleted item, but not the expression itself.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser oh yes i fixed on demo. but forgot to fix on expression. fixed now. btw thanks for pointing out.

Comment: `+` or `-` are optional after `e`.  Currently your pattern doesn't match `.123e2`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser this one i kept it as per op asked. in the examples given in questions. i know technically it should be optional.

Comment: About `.123e2`:  The question says "How can I create a regular expression for accepting numbers in Python".  The Python interpreter accepts `.123e2` as a valid floating point number.  In the question, the only examples given have a sign after `e`, so maybe Mihika isn't looking to match the generality of the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?(e[+-]\d+)?
```

This matches:

```
100
100.123
100e+3
100.123e-3
```

### Demo

Comment: I like your regex exp, and I extend yours like: `^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)` It will only match numbers at begining

Comment: @YangHG Depending on how the OP plans to use the pattern in his Python script, the starting and ending anchors may be inappropriate.

Comment: it also matches 001

Comment: And your point is?  Do you have reason to expect such a value?

Comment: About `.123e2`: the Python interpreter accepts that as a valid floating point number.  In the question, the only examples given have a sign after `e`, so maybe Mihika isn't looking to match the generality of the Python interpreter.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I flagged your comments for removal.  Let's wait for feedback from the OP before we run around trying to cover edge cases of which we are not even sure are there.

Comment: Agreed about waiting for clarification... but flag for removal?  I guess I don't know how comment flags are supposed to be used.