# Adding a column in Spark from existing column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

So my generated dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|constraint_message                                                   |constraint_status|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|                                                                     |Success          |
|Value: 8.109213053982745E-6 does not meet the constraint requirement!|Failure          |
|                                                                     |Success          |
|                                                                     |Success          |
|Value: 0.98 does not meet the constraint requirement!                |Failure          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I want to have a new column in this dataframe, the logic for which I've defined in the function:

```
def metric = (status: String, valu:Double) => {
  if (status == "Success"){ 1 }  
  else{ valu } 
}
val putMetric = spark.udf.register("Metric",metric)
```

Now when I'm calling it like this:
[Note: I'll later replace the 0 by a Double variable]

`df.withColumn("Metric",putMetric(col("constraint_status"),0)).show()`

I get the error:

```
try.scala:48: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
    df.withColumn("Metric",putMetric(col("constraint_status"),0))
```

How to rectify this? I tried putting `col(0)` but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53863232/14165730):

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "newcol",
    when(
        col("constraint_message").isNull || length(col("constraint_message")) === 0,
        lit(1)
    )
    .otherwise(
        regexp_extract(
            col("constraint_message"),
            raw"(\d+(\.\d+)?(E[+-]\d+)?)",
            1
        )
    )
    .cast("double")
)

df2.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|constraint_message                                                   |constraint_status|newcol              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|null                                                                 |Success          |1.0                 |
|Value: 8.109213053982745E-6 does not meet the constraint requirement!|Failure          |8.109213053982745E-6|
|null                                                                 |Success          |1.0                 |
|null                                                                 |Success          |1.0                 |
|Value: 0.98 does not meet the constraint requirement!                |Failure          |0.98                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_extract`

```
val df1 = df.withColumn(
  "passed",
  when(
    col("constraint_status") === "Failure",
    regexp_extract(col("constraint_message"), "Value: (\\d*\\.?\\d+([e|E][+-]?[0-9]+)?).*", 1)
  ).otherwise(1).cast("double")
)

df1.show
//+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
//|  constraint_message|constraint_status|              passed|
//+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
//|                    |          Success|                   1|
//|Value: 8.10921305...|          Failure|8.109213053982745E-6|
//|                    |          Success|                   1|
//|                    |          Success|                   1|
//|Value: 0.98 does ...|          Failure|                0.98|
//+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```